# Xamarin Forms - adding the calling object as a parameter on a tap gesture recognizer

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, gesture

What is the correct syntax for adding the image in the XAML below as the parameter on the Command?

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding Source}" Aspect="AspectFit" CacheType="Memory" Opacity="2" x:Name="smallImage" >
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                    Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.SetImageCommand, Source={x:Reference this}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding smallImage}" />
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

And the command code it's bound to (CustomCachedImage is just a class derived from a cached image, with an imageName field added)

There will be multiple instances of the calling image as it is in a data template as part of an image slider, so I can't just get the control by name I have to make sure it is the calling control being passed.

```
public ICommand SetImageCommand
        {
            get
            {
                 return new Command<CustomCachedImage>((_image) =>
                 {
                     string imgName = _image.ImageName;
                     SetImg(imgName);
                 });
             }
        }
```

Comment: Please show the object that you bind to it

Comment: thanks, post updated

Comment: Please post all relevant code :-) What does `SetImg` do and where does `smallImage` come from?

Comment: There is a larger main image, the tap gesture recognizer calls SetImg which set the image to the same source as the smaller image in the slider the user has tapped.  Everything else works I just can't seem to pass the tapped image as a parameter to the command.

Comment: Should have mentioned, the image sources can be either bundled in the app or held in local storage, hence the custom cahcedImage.  If I can pass the image, I can grab the image name and do the rest easily.

Comment: smallImage is the name of the image being clicked, the one I want to pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed "{Binding smallImage}" to "{Binding .}" and I got what I needed